# PowerMock - Suppress constructor but set private final field

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

When suppressing the constructor of a class using powermock, how can I set the value of a private final field?

suppressing the constructor:

```
suppress(constructor(ABC.class, MyType.class));
ABC abc = spy(new ABC(null)); // using the correct value doesn't work
abc.someMethod();
```

the class to be tested:

```
class ABC {
    private final MyType test;

    public ABC(MyType test) {
        this.test = test;

        // executes code to be suppressed
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        test.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you normally would, by using reflection:

```
Field f = ABC.class.getDeclaredField("test");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(abc, new MyType());
```

This is not related to mocking and therefore nothing a mocking framework would target in its API. You should consider to refactor for testing.